# auto generate email using users name input

Tags: firebase, react-native

using react native

so what i'm trying to accomplish is when a user registers, the email filled is auto generated (this part i can get to work) the part i'm having trouble with is after clicking submit the fullname in the email filled dissapears and i get an error saying the email is badly formatted - using firebase/firestore

```
<View style={styles.action}>
<FontAwesome name="user-o" color="#05375a" size={24} />
<TextInput placeholder="Your Full Name" style={styles.textInput} autoCapitalize="none" onCh</View>

<Text style={styles.textFooter}>Email</Text>
<View style={styles.action}>
<MaterialIcons name="alternate-email" color="#05375a" size={24} />
<TextInput placeholder="Entered Automatically" style={styles.textInput} editable={false} selectTextOnFocus={false} value={fullName.replace(/\s/g, '.') + '@sameemail.com'} onChangeText={text => setEmail({ fullName }, { text })} />
</View>
```

so what i was trying to do was as the user enters there full name it updates the value in the email input which is disabled for editing, so everytime a user signs up there full name is used as the email address for example joe bloggs signs up and there email is auto populated with joe.bloggs@sameemail.com and this would be the same result for all registered users

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way you are setting the email value is making it invalid. Since email is not editable, you can just show the value from fullname, no need to call the onChangeText function inside email textinput and set the value there.

So you can set the state of your fullname and email inside the onChangeText function of the fullName TextInput. Like this -

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
  setFullName(text);
  setEmail(text.replace(/\s/g, '.') + '@sameemail.com')
}}
```

and your email textInput should be like this -

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Auto generated from full name"
    editable={false}
    value={email}
/>
```

You should be able to get your FullName and Email state values correctly when you press submit button. I have created a snack for you so that you can get the full idea of this. Here is the link - *https://snack.expo.io/@saad-bashar/auto-email-from-name*

Comment: thank you very much, this works perfectly just the way i wanted it, next thing to do now is workout the best way to create dropdown options for registering

Comment: Glad that it worked out. If this is working fine for your question, can you mark the answer as accepted? :)